# "Only the first element of list is used" in R

Tags: r, list

a, b and c are lists. List "a" and "b" have the same number of objects and elements.

```
a<-list(c(3,4,5),c(1,3))
b<-list(c(5,8,7),c(6,8))
c<-list(10,9)

> a
[[1]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 3

> b
[[1]]
[1] 5 8 7

[[2]]
[1] 6 8

> c
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 9
```

I want to calculate the sum of "choose(c,a:b)" in corresponding position. The expected result is a list which also has two objects containing 3 and 2 elements, respectively. Just as:

```
[[1]]
[1] X1 X2 X3

[[2]]
[1] Y1 Y2
```

For example: X1=sum(choose(10, 3:5)), X2=sum(choose(10, 4:8)), Y1=sum(choose(9, 1:6))......

I try to use the following code to calculate:

```
mapply(function(a,b,c) sum(choose(c,a:b)), a,b,c)
```

but I get the warnings:

```
[1] 582 465
Warning messages:
1: In a:b : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
2: In a:b : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
3: In a:b : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
4: In a:b : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
```

Only the first element in each object has been used, can you help me to figure it out? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can either use a `lapply/mapply` combination

```
lapply(seq_along(a), function(i) 
  mapply(function(x,y,z) sum(choose(z,x:y)), a[[i]], b[[i]], c[[i]]))
 #[[1]]
 #[1] 582 837 582

 #[[2]]
 #[1] 465 465
```

Or a double `Map/mapply` or `mapply/mapply`

```
Map(function(x,y,z) mapply(function(x,y,z) 
        sum(choose(z, x:y)) , x,y, z) , a, b, c)
```

---

The reason why the OP got the Warning message is based on the `:`.  We get the corresponding `list` elements with `Map`, but each element in 'a', 'b' is also a vector of length greater than 1.  The `:` can only take a single sequence based on the corresponding vector element.  In order to get all the sequence of the corresponding vector elements, we need to loop again.  So a second `Map/mapply` is used.

Comment: Thank you! Oh, The `:` is the reason, no wonder I can calculate `"a+b"`, but can't calculate `:`.